# Determine number of rows returns from SQLite.swift raw query

Tags: swift, sqlite, sqlite.swift

I am using the SQLite.swift library and running raw queries.

I have the following

```
let results = try db!.prepare("""
    SELECT class from "character" where character_id = ?
""", character.id
)
```

Does anyone know how to get the number of rows returned? (or more specifically whether it returns any rows).

I know I can loop through results, but was looking for a more efficient way.

Comment: Are you only interested in counting the rows or do you want to return the data as well?

Answer (score 0):

You can add a subquery with the count to your query

```
CREATE TABLE "character"(character_id int, class varchar(120))
```

```
SELECT class, (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM  "character" where character_id = 1) count_ 
  from "character" where character_id = 1
```

| class | count_ |
| --- | --- |

```
SELECT class, _count
  from "character" CROSS JOIN (SELECT COUNT(*) _count FROM  "character" where character_id = 1) count_
  where character_id = 1
```

| class | _count |
| --- | --- |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/xq84VLU1)

Comment: Besides being very inefficient, why do this? Every result row will have the same value for count. Either the OP only wants a count or the OP needs each result row and the count. If the latter, it's far more efficient to count the rows in code while iterating each result.

Comment: it is not inefficient , it is a normal way in sql, to join the data in every row and you wanted it all in one sql statement. if you use two statements it will not be faster

Comment: Let's say there are 10,000 rows in the table and 6,000 have a matching character_id. Doesn't this mean the count subquery will perform a full table scan 6,000 times, once for each matching row? And since each count will be the same, doing it 6,000 times instead of just once does seem inefficient. If there's an appropriate index, it will be a bit more efficient but you still perform the subquery 6,000 times even though every one of them gives the same result.

Comment: the code is parsed once and will be calculated only once, then join is with 6000 fast, the count is usually slow, with increasing number it will get slower and slower, so try it and see

Answer (score 0):

If you have no need to process each matching class and you only want the number of matching classes, then change the query to:

```sql
SELECT COUNT(class) from "character" where character_id = ?
```

This will give you one result row with one column containing the number of matching classes.

If you do need to process each class and you want the count, then use your existing query as-is and calculate the count as you process each result row.